# Bukkit Permission Nodes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, server-administration

I have a question about permission nodes in Bukkit. I want to give my moderators the ability to define and redefine their own regions but not regions that they are members of. I found WorldGuard's permission nodes [here](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Permissions). If a permission node has a child node, do I have to include the parent? For example ...

Do I do this and include the `worldguard.region.redefine` permission

```
- worldguard.region.define
- worldguard.region.claim
- worldguard.region.redefine
- worldguard.region.redefine.own
```

Or should I do this and not include the `worldguard.region.redefine` permission

```
- worldguard.region.define
- worldguard.region.claim
- worldguard.region.redefine.own
```

If I give them the `worldguard.region.redefine` permission will it also give them the `worldguard.region.redefine.member` permission?

Comment: IF you know how to use imports in the Java programming language, permission nodes work the same way.

Comment: @SaintWacko I never thought of it that way! I have been programming in Java for about 4 years and now it makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: Heh, no problem. I just realized that myself yesterday. Should I put that as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving them `worldguard.region.redefine` will not give them `worldguard.region.redefine.member`, using a wild card will do that: `worldguard.region.redefine.*`. It may be obvious, but it wasn't to me at first, that using that wild card will not give them `worldguard.region.redefine`.

Given your current situation, I would say to use the first set up, because they need permission to redefine regions in the first place.